# Drawing a saddle on a contour graph

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions

When drawing a contour graph of say,

$f(x,y) = \frac12x^2 + \frac13y^3 - xy - x + y$

, there is a saddle point at point $(1,0)$. How can I determine the slopes of the two lines that meet at this point when a contour graph of $f(x,y) = 0.5$?(ie. on the level of point (1,0))

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{x} = (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be a point, and $f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x}_0)$ be the contour line passing through point $\mathbf{x}_0$. By Taylor expansion around $\mathbf{x}_0$ we have

\begin{equation}
   f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x}_0) + \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_0) (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0) + \frac{1}{2!} (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0)^{\intercal}\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{x}_0) (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0) + \mathcal{O}\left( \left| \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0 \right|^3 \right),
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{x})$ is the Hessian matrix,

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{x}) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} \\
\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

For all $\mathbf{x}$ on the contour line we have $f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x}_0)$. Also if $\mathbf{x}_0$ is a saddle point, we have $\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_0) = \mathbf{0}$. Thus, the Taylor expansion *on the contour curve* and in the vicinity of $\mathbf{x}_0$ becomes

\begin{equation}
   0 = \frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0)^{\intercal}\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{x}_0) (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0) + \mathcal{O}\left( \left| \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0 \right|^3 \right)
\end{equation}

When $\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{x}_0$, the higher order terms vanish. We want to find the direction vector $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_0$ such that

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{r}^{\intercal} \mathbf{H}(\mathbf{x}_0) \mathbf{r} = 0.
\end{equation}

Here $\mathbf{r}$ is a vector, that when $\mathbf{x} \to \mathbf{x}_0$, becomes tangent to the contour curve at saddle point $\mathbf{x}_0$. Once we found $\mathbf{r}$, its direction is what you are asking.

In your example,

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{H}(x=1,y=0) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Let $\mathbf{r} = (r_x,r_y)$ be components of $\mathbf{r}$. Then

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
r_x & r_y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
r_x \\ r_y
\end{bmatrix} = 0
\end{equation}

or $r_x(r_x - r_y) - r_x r_y = 0$. Solving yields $\mathbf{r} = (0,1)$ or $\mathbf{r} = (2,1)$, which solution is unique upto a scale factor. Thus two directions of intersecting controur lines are

\begin{equation}
\theta = \tan^{-1}(r_y/r_x) =
\begin{cases}
90^{\circ} \\ 26.56^{\circ}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Here is a plot, that at $(x=1,y = 0)$ two contour lines $f(1,0) = 0.5$ intersect, with slopes $+\infty$ and $1/2$.

[image]